# Windows key + arrow now controls brightness instead of moving windows around (windwos 10)

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

I bought a new monitor and suddenly the combination "Windows key + right/left arrow" no longer moves windows around or to the other monitor, now it controls brightness. Also when I change brightness doing that, my monitor changes its configuration and even if I set the brightness to the same level it looks different.

If that is not weird enough when I turn off the new screen this behavior stops.

I disabled DDC/CI support but I'm still able to change the brightness from windows.

How can I enable the Windows key + arrow controls windows instead of brightness and why changing the brightness from windows mess with my monitor configuration?

This happened with my AMD Radeon R9 200 series and now I have updated my GPU to a GTX2060 and still happens.

Comment: there is only one driver, no matter which monitor I connect. I added it to the post. Also, If I turn off the new monitor, brightness on the other monitor restarts to the default value

Comment: did you accidentally press `Fn` instead of `Windows`

Comment: Many OEMs enable a setting in BIOS/UEFI firmware settings that defaults the functions keys to ON so that `FN` doesn't need to be pressed to access the function keys, and instead the `FN` must be pressed to access the normal key values.  You either must press `FN` every time (i.e. `FN`+`WinKey`+`arrow` right/left or it might be `WinKey`+`FN`+`arrow` right/left ), or disable this setting in the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings.

Comment: @phuclv is not a laptop, I don't have a Fn key

Comment: @JW0914  is not a laptop, I don't have a Fn key, plus this didn't happen a few weeks ago with the same motherboard and BIOS configuration

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez The arrow keys adjusting brightness is a special function almost always assigned to the arrow keys by an OEM... please check the BIOS/UEFI Firmware settings, as well as your PC's manual and OEM's support site.

Comment: Turns out the problem was a program that hijacked that hotkey. I disabled it and now everything works as expected

Comment: @GonzaloHernandez can you tell us which program that was? I have the same issue and it's highly frustrating. Edit: for me it was Volume²

Comment: @Métoule Yes, it's exactly that program. But there is an option to disable that. If you can't find it I can tell you where it is when I get home

Comment: Hi Gonzalo! How can I turn on this ability to increase/decrease brightness by Win+arrow? In my case i want to turn it ON :) Upd.: Ok, I figured it out! There is Hotkeys setting and I need to specify this combination by myself

Answer (score 2):

Like two other users, I ran into the same problem when I got a new monitor, after making it my primary display, due to the Volume² program hijacking the "Win" + "(arrow key)" hotkeys to use for volume/brightness controls instead.
Volume² is a great tool, but yeah it hijacked the useful Win key shortcuts for easy screen management. Maybe substitute it to "Win" + "PgUp/Dn" etc. instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).